# Any one else having problems connecting to IMAP Servers with Thunderbird 16.0.1?

Tags: thunderbird

Recently I've had problems connected to an Exchange server configured with IMAP.  The configuration used to work until the system updated to 16.0.1. - now I get: *"Connection to Server XXX timed out error"* each time I connect.

Although I sit behind a proxy, Thunderbird has no problems finding extensions or add-ons (which suggests that the internet works) and I have tested the IMAP server with an earlier version of Thunderbird (3.x) on Windows and got lots of e-mail which suggest the server works.

Is anyone else having this problem or if not are there any tips for generating more information on the situation?

Comment: What OS are you using? None of the *current/supported* Ubuntu flavors have a Thunderbird that old. For example, I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 to make this comment and my Thunderbird is version `68.10.0`. The current newest version is `78.10.1`.

Comment: Voting to close this ancient question - OP reported that "So it looks like a local configuration or network problem rather than a problem with Thunderbird. " Stop the Community Bot bumping this!

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my own question.  After more testing I can connect to the IMAP server with almost *anything* except the machine in question behind the proxy...

So it looks like a local configuration or network problem rather than a problem with Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

To help Answer your question, Oddly enough it helps to set the system proxy, but then in Thunderbird itself go to:

Edit> Preferences> Advanced> Network> Connections> and set Thunderbird to use NO PROXY

For some reason... it works... here is the link to where I found it

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=2449619